# tricky apache rewrite configuration

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I have a URL of the form

http://example.com/fetchjobs.action?jobType=crons&jobList=foo&categoryModeId=0&showOnlyLatest=true

And I want to redirect above url to url below

http://newexample.com/crons?jobList=foo&categoryModeId=0&showOnlyLatest=true

Note:

1. domain got changed from example.com to newexample.com.
2. Value of "jobType" is in a URL path now instead of query param. (jobType=crons vs /crons?)
3. All other query parameters are retained as query params in a new URL.
4. There can be any number of query parameters in source URL.

Leads here is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)?jobType\=([^\&]+)&?(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^     http://newsite.com/%2??%1%3  [L,R=301,NE]
```

**Note:** clear browser cache the test it .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166754/discussion-between-lokesh-agrawal-and-mohammed-elhag).